# Organizar lista com mais de um critério em caso de empate

Tags: python, classificação

Estou usando `sorted` para organizar uma lista, porém preciso de dois critérios para organizá-la para casos de empate, para isso, chamo `sorted( )` duas vezes. Tem como fazer essa organização chamando `sorted( )` apenas uma vez?

Basicamente, assim que está o código:

```
lista_intermediaria = sorted(minha_lista, key = funcao_comparacao_1)
lista_organizada = sorted(lista_intermediaria, key = funcao_comparacao_2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumindo que as funções de comparação não são excessivamente caras, o que você pode fazer é retornar uma tupla com o resultado da primeira função na posição `0` e o resultado da segunda na posição `1`:

```
lista_organizada = sorted(minha_lista, key=lambda x:
    (funcao_comparacao_2(x), funcao_comparacao_1(x)))
```

Assim, primeiro os elementos serão comparados pelo critério 2 e - se o resultado der igual - então eles serão comparados pelo critério 1 (nota: coloquei o 2 antes do 1 para ficar consistente com o que você está fazendo).